# What is the correct .NET encoding format to use to decode a string that has been encoded using PHPs rawurlencode?

Tags: php, .net, unicode, encoding

I have a bunch of strings which I'm told have been encoded using the `rawurlencode` function in PHP.

Some of these strings contain percent encoded sequences for characters above unicode codepoint 127 - e.g. `a%A0b`.

I *think* the `A0` in the above example is meant to represent a non-breaking space (Unicode codepoint 160 0xA0) but `A0` on it's own is not a valid UTF-8 sequence (any byte with the high bit set (>127) is part of a multi-sequence). Thus .NET decodes this to `?` by default.

I have tried a few different encodings. `iso-8859-1` seems to fit, but I can't be sure.

This URL encoded string *will* contain non-english characters so it is critical that the conversion happens properly.

Which is the correct encoding to pass to `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to decode a string that has been encoded with `rawurlencode`?

Answer (score 1):

PHP's native string type is plain old bytes, with no encoding information attached. So `rawurlencode` doesn't do any handling of Unicode, it just hex-escapes each high byte to %xx.

If the application wants to treat those bytes as a representation of characters, it's up to the application to decide what encoding is in use. It would be lovely if the application told you that in the documentation, and it would be lovely if that encoding were UTF-8 which is the only sane choice. But apparently not.

> `iso-8859-1` seems to fit, but I can't be sure.

There are a lot of encodings that map character U+00A0 Non Breaking Space to byte 0xA0, including all the ISO-8859s and all the Windows code pages that are based on them. True ISO-8859-1 is relatively rare on the web, you're more likely to meet its mutant cousin Windows Western code page 1252 (`GetEncoding(1252)`).

The only way to tell would be to enter different characters into the application and see what comes out. What “non-English” characters are you expecting, any particular language?

Comment: This is the answer I was afraid of. I already (since asking this question) tried entering a bunch of characters into the system. The output was, shall we say weird. So I need to talk to the php developer to figure it out. My input string contained the sequence `%22`. The % did not get encoded and so on the output it was decoded to double quote!  For this reason I think the problems go deeper than simple which encoding to use.